# Сравнение объектов по свойству

Tags: python-3.x

Прошу помощи:

допустим есть массив

```
ships_array = []
```

есть класс корабль с полем координата

```
class Ship:
    def __init__(self):
        self.coords = [randint(0, 5), randint(0, 5)]
```

в массив добавили 5 объектов:

```
for i in range(5):
    ships_array.append(Ship())
```

## есть задача:

создать класс лодка с такими координатами чтобы они не совпали ни с одним из объектов класса Ship

```
class Boat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.coords = ?
```

Помогите пожалуйста - никак не соображу как правильно сравнивать объекты по полям. 
Т.е. я понимаю, что нужно генерировать свойство лодки также через randint и в цикле сравнивать его со свойством всех экземплярами в массиве до тех пор пока оно не окажется уникальным, но как это реализовать в коде не пойму.

Comment: Нужно просто объявить в класса [метод сравнения](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю передать экземпляры лодок, с которыми нужно сравнивать, в метод `__init__`, а дальше всё как Вы сказали:

```py
from random import randint


class Ship:
    def __init__(self):
        self.coords = [randint(0, 5), randint(0, 5)]


class Boat:
    def __init__(self, ships):
        while True:
            coords = [randint(0, 5), randint(0, 5)]
            if coords not in [ship.coords for ship in ships]:
                self.coords = coords
                break


ships_array = []
for i in range(5):
    ships_array.append(Ship())

boat = Boat(ships_array)
```

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо огромное!